# How to storyboard a switching container view controller?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, storyboard

Is there a way to story board a custom container view controller that behaves very similarly to a `UITabBarController`?

My container view controller is similar to an `UITabBarController` in that:

- it switches the content of the screen
- in response to the user actioning some widget

But it differs from an `UITabBarController` in that:

- it switches only part of the screen (materialized by a rectangle frame on the screen)
- the user action to initiate the switch involves specific `UIControl`s instead of the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

Beside that, I would very much like to story board my app in a very similar way an `UITabBarController` is storyboarded:

- One scene represent the container view, with all the content that is not switched
- As many children scenes as I have possible switchable content for the frame.
- One segue from each switching control to its corresponding child scene.

However, I haven't been able to achieve that. Is there a way (better than perhaps artificially making my switching container view controller a subclass of `UITabBarController`)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is one of the areas where storyboarding is much less useful than it should be.

From what I see, you can drop in all your switch-inducing-widgets manually, wire them to their respective target view controllers and configure the resulting segues to be instances of your custom `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass(es) that override(s) `perform` and optionally implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your container view-controller…but (a) you’ve probably figured that out already and (b) to me, that hardly sounds like what you are aiming for in the first place.

For this and other reasons, I would (and have done so…) *avoid* storyboards in such a scenario altogether and — instead — use a NIB in conjunction with an `IBOutletCollection` (unsupported in storyboards — you cannot connect anything to them!) for the view controllers.

In my case, I could then dynamically fill the segments of a `UISegmentedControl` or rows of a `UITableView` using the title/image properties of the `tabBarItem`s of the connected view controllers.

This is, however, a **tradeoff**, as you *lose* the ability to configure the transitions between your view controllers in IB. Additionally, it relies on the implied contract that a view controller has a properly configured `tabBarItem` *which cannot be expressed* in IB.

In my case, that didn’t matter but your mileage may vary wildly!

Splitting the layout and use of the container into separate NIBs helped keeping things simple.